# Move FlexSlider at center of page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, flexslider

I work on small site, and have problem with FlexSlider position. I use the same template for 2 sites but with different language. Now when i copy the CSS from  second site, it not apply the changes and gallery looks different on second site. To explain with image. **[Original Site](https://echographie-sans-frontieres.com/gallery-item/divers/)** :

[image]

**[New Site](http://www.echographie-maroc.com)**: (Login is user / password )

[image]

And this is [link](http://www.echographie-maroc.com/gallery-item/divers/) to affected page. (previous must be logged in)

I tryed to insert this CSS :

```
/* Gallery Center */
.col-lg-7 {width:100%;}
.flex-active-slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

But this just set in center of block , and not in center of page, as first site. Any help how to get at center like first linked site? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
/* Gallery Center */
.col-lg-7 {min-width:100%;}
.flex-active-slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The browser may scale based on this or you can create a separate DIV the width of the page and then use `margin: auto;` for the contents and just place the slider inside it.

```css
.centerslider {
min-width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.slidercontents {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=centerslider>
<div class=slidercontents>
<h1>Place the slider here</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tryed this but not seems to changed something.

Comment: Please edit your question and add slider code + css.

Comment: Slider is inserted using theme template. So i cant find it slider code.